# d3 append an image with svg extension

Tags: javascript, image, svg, d3.js, xlink

I'm trying to add an svg image with '.svg' extension to my chart (another svg image created with d3).

This is the code:

```
d3.select("#chart1 svg")
  .append("svg:image")
  .attr("xlink:href", "img/icons/sun.svg")
  .attr("width", 40)
  .attr("height", 40)
  .attr("x", 228)
  .attr("y",53);
```

As you can see I'm setting "xlink:href" attribute, but d3 changes this to href in the browser:

```
<image href="img/icons/sun.svg" width="40" height="40" x="228" y="53"></image>
```

In fact, this code works perfectly if I use png extension. Any idea?

Comment: I am having issues with that too. Apparently, D3 removes the prefix if the prefix is a known namespace. Here there is more details about namespaces: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Namespaces

Comment: As long as the attribute is added with `setAttributeNS` it works just fine in all browsers (and to be clear D3 does this). The missing prefix on the attribute itself is really only an issue if you want document/element serialization to be done in a particular way.

Comment: Looks like this is still a thing today... Has anybody found a solution so far?

Answer (score 17):

The code should work as is - here you can see an example of attaching an .svg file to d3:

http://jsfiddle.net/am8ZB/

Don't forget that it's possible the picture is actually there but you just can't see it-
you should inspect the page using the browser developer tools to see whether the picture has been placed out of the view area (due to your x/y values, for example).

more info on `#chart1` would help in this case.

Comment: Is it possible to implement the svg into the DOM?

Comment: what is #chart1 ?